# Had an extra > character when moving a file, now the folder is missing

Tags: move

I tried moving a file in Linux from one directory to another and accidentally had an extra > character.

```
mv /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/>test2.dbf /u01/shared_data/oradata/TEST/test.dbf
```

Now, my entire `dbs` folder is missing.  However when I locate the `dbs` folder `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs` it appears to be there but I can't `ll` or `cd` to it:

```
-bash: cd: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs: No such file or directory
```

How do I get the original back to where it was?

Comment: I suspect you renamed the dbs directory to test.dbf.

Comment: I can't tell you where the directory has gone to, but the reason you still see it as being present, is because you use "locate" to search for it. "locate" searches in a database which is updated daily. You should probably use "find".

Comment: DOH!  You are right stolenmoment.  I was able to locate the file and move it back to the original name.  I guess the > character moves all items into a new directory?  Can't find it on the mv man pages.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `>` here redirects stdout to a file, like it would in a more normal use case:

```bash
printf "%s\n" "hello world" > filename
```

The spaces around `>` are optional, and it doesn't have to go at the end. This does the same:

```bash
printf "%s\n">filename "hello world"
```

So your `mv` line would more conventionally be written:

```bash
mv /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/ /u01/shared_data/oradata/TEST/test.dbf > test2.dbf
```

which has renamed your folder to `test.dbf` (in a different directory) and written `mv`'s stdout (probably nothing) to `test2.dbf` in your current directory. Hopefully that didn't accidentally overwrite an Oracle datafile.

PS: If extra `>` are a frequent problem, bash's `set -o noclobber`/`set -C` option can at least help prevent overwriting files. The bash manpage describes it as: *If  set, bash does not overwrite an existing file with the `>`, `>&`, and `<>` redirection operators.  This may be overridden when creating output files by  using the redirection operator `>|` instead of `>`.*

Comment: Excellent explanation derobert +1.  Everything is working normal again after moving all items back to their original location.

Comment: @rman Glad to hear that. Worst case, considering your username, I figured you'd just restore a backup ☺.